# How Can I get rid of Container Disk 1 on mac?

Tags: disk-utility

It takes 30 GB of space on my Mac, and it is an apfs container. How do I delete it? I used a command using terminal on a different post, and that did not help. When I tried partitioning it, the - part was greyed out. Any solutions?

Comment: Can you post the output from the command `diskutil list`?

Comment: Also, which command did you run, from which other post?